# Calculate $\max_{(x,y)\in V}\left\{\frac{(x+y)^2}{8(y-x)} \, , \, x \right\}$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Calculate
$$\max_{(x,y)\in V}\left\{\frac{(x+y)^2}{8(y-x)} \, , \, x \right\}$$
where
$$V:=\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\, : \, 0\leq \frac{x+y}{2(y-x)}\leq1 \, , \, x\geq0\, , \, y\geq 0\right\}\, .$$
Any hints how to do that would be appreciated.

Comment: so you just want the maximum of that expression in the given range?

Comment: or the maximum of that and x?

Comment: or the maximum of (the maximum and that and x)

Comment: no maximum, try $y=3x$